# Vlookup in R with keeping an empty cell where it does not match

Tags: r, dataframe, vlookup

Hi I have two data frames

Data frame a

[image]

Data frame b

[image]

I want put the food column in dataframe a from b based on animal name and if the animal name is not there it should come as NA
This is what I am expecting

[image]

was trying with merge function in R but getting error

Comment: What code did you try with `merge`? `merge(a, b, by = 'Animal', all.x = TRUE)` should work for your data.

Comment: Hi Ronak  ,  actually this is just an example what i put here  how can i specifically mention column food in the code , what i am trying is of a huge dataset having 1000 columns and above code will merge the entire dataframe

Comment: You can select the columns that you want to merge. `merge(a, b[c('food', 'Animal')], by = 'Animal', all.x = TRUE)`